# How to access telerik controls from telerik radgrid

Tags: asp.net

How to access telerik control that is RadAsyncUpload from below radgrid. I have below code in aspx page. During page load I need to disable telerik controls on some condition. How can I disable telerik controls from below code?

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1"
                 runat="server"
                 AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                 GridLines="None"
                 Skin="Black" 
                 Width="750px"
                 Height="320px">
  <PagerStyle Mode="NextPrevAndNumeric" />
  <SelectedItemStyle CssClass="SelectedItem"/>                        
  <MasterTableView EditMode="InPlace"
                   CommandItemDisplay="None"
                   AllowFilteringByColumn="True"
                   DataKeyNames="FileName">
    <Columns>
      <telerik:GridBoundColumn ReadOnly="true"
                               DataField="FileName"
                               UniqueName="FileName"
                               AllowFiltering="false"
                               ItemStyle-Width="200px"
                               HeaderStyle-Width="205px"
                               HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
                               ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
                               ItemStyle-BackColor="Gray">
      </telerik:GridBoundColumn> 
      <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="FilePath"
                                  Visible="true"
                                  ItemStyle-Width="310px"
                                  HeaderStyle-Width="355px"
                                  HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
                                  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
                                  AllowFiltering="false"
                                  ItemStyle-BackColor="Gray">
        <ItemTemplate>                                        
          <telerik:RadAsyncUpload runat="server" ID="RadUpload1">
          </telerik:RadAsyncUpload>
        </ItemTemplate>
      </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
    </Columns>
  </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

Comment: please provide your problem in detail. Are you want to disabled RadAsyncUpload control or else?

Comment: ya only i have disable RadAsyncUpload control during page load on executing some condition..

Answer (score 0):

You would be disable RadAsyncUpload Control during DataBinding / DataBound Item events of RadGrid.

DataBinding / DataBound are events Occurs when the server control binds to a data source.
(Inherited from Control.)

When you bind a RadGrid Control. for ex.

```
     protected void Page_Load(object sender,System.EventArgs e)
      {
          if(!IsPostBack)
          {
// Here I creates temporary datatable..
// you can generate dynamic DataTable from SQL query to fill DataSet/DataTable.
// Here I created temp DataTable for Binding RadGrid grid control..
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("temp");        

            RadGrid.DataSource= dt;
            RadGrid.DataBind();
            // It will event fired When you binding data source.
            // If You have to added "RadGrid_ItemDataBound" Item bound event to the <RADGRID >... control.
          }
       }
          protected void RadGrid_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
            {
               if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
               {
                  RadAsyncUpload asyncUpload = (RadAsyncUpload) e.Item.FindControl("RadAsyncUploadControlID");     
                  bool blUploadControlHide=true;
                  if(asyncUpload  !=null) 
                  {
                     if(blUploadControlHide)
                     {   
                       asyncUpload.Enabled = false;
                       //If you can hide then write asyncUpload.Visible = false;
                     }
                     else
                     {
                       asyncUpload.Enabled = true;
                     }
                   }     
               }
            }
```

Refer [Radgrid Events](http://www.sitefinity.com/help/developer-manual/radgrid.net2-telerik.webcontrols.radgrid_events.html)

Thanks

Comment: ...i am not getting in radgrid events..can u provide sloution

Comment: Thanq..on which condtion this event will fire...please help i am new for asp.net...

Comment: @user1177921 When Items bound of RADGrid control it will fired.. you can check by putting breakpoint.

Comment: @user1177921  saw the above example as I mention above.

Comment: ..thanq so much..nice solution

Comment: @user1177921 welcome man.. pls Accept as a answer if u satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

you can hook into ItemDataBound event of RadGrid, then find the control , you can check this links. [Telerik RadGrid - databound Events.](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/controls/examples/integration/gridandradasyncupload/defaultcs.aspx?product=upload)

```
SomeGrid_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
{
RadAsyncUpload objUpload = (RadAsyncUpload) e.Item.FindControl("RadUpload1"); 

if(opbjUpload !=null) 
{
   // do some thing with Upload Obj.
}

}
}
```

Comment: thanq...how to i disable RadAsyncUpload control in condition

Comment: @user1177921 u need to bind in itemDataBound events